# Is there R method for DataFrames like index_col in Python Pandas?

Tags: r, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I feel like R probably has something really simple for this since it's R.  I looked in the documentation for `as.data.frame` and `read.table` or `read.csv` but I can't find it.  Looking to label one of the columns as the indices, not renaming the current indices as labels.
Example:

## R

```
pDF_data = read.table("file.path",sep="\t")
DF_data = as.data.frame(pDF_data)
  X      V1
0 labelA 33
1 labelB 22
2 labelC 35

#I tried `rownames(DF_data) = DF_data$X` but got

row.names      X      V1
labelA         labelA 33
labelB         labelB 22
labelC         labelC 35
```

I just want:

```
row.names V1
labelA    33
labelB    22
labelC    35
```

In Python, this would be:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_table("file.path",sep="\t",index_col=0)
```

Comment: `DF_data$X <- NULL` can be used to drop the column from the DF after you've set the names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the first column as the row names with `row.names = 1`.

```
pDF_data <- read.table("file.path", sep = "\t", row.names = 1)
```

P.S. You don't need to coerce `pDF_data` to a data frame, as `read.table()` returns a data frame already.  So your second line of code is irrelevant.

Now that I read the question again, you may just be looking for

```
names(pDF_data)[1] <- "row.names"
```

but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: thanks! i knew it had to be something simple.  I may have tried that but forgot to do View(DF_data) to look at the updated one. Thought it autoupdated